# Kinect Hovering event handler

Tags: c#, kinect

I am creating a WPF application using Kinect SDK 1.8
I want to press a button with hand.

```
private void playTeeth1Sound(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer teeth1_Sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"../../soundForKinect/1.wav");
        teeth1_Sound.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any Kinect specific code in your question, and I'm not sure what the questions is, but one thing to consider in the code snippet in your question is:

Every time this method is called (presumably when the button is pressed), it has to:

1. instantiate a new **System.Media.SoundPlayer**
2. load the sound file into *teeth1_Sound*
3. play the sound file with the **Play()** method

You might find there is a delay each time as the code re-instantiates *teeth1_Sound* and reloads the sound file? It might be easier to load all the sound files when the app is starting up, have them ready to **Play()** as soon as you need them?